# recognizing a select on Apple TV remote

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos

My app for Apple tv is pulling audio from a URL and playing it. However on pressing the Button again it needs to pause.

therefor i added a addTarget to the UIButton to see if it is playing audio or not.

this is in my ViewDidLoad

```
player = AVPlayer(url:url)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 50))
playerLayer.frame = rect
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
playButton.addTarget(self, action: "plays:", for: UIControlEvents.primaryActionTriggered )
```

the function `plays`

```
func plays(sender: UIButton!){
    NSLog("Clicked")
    if player?.rate ==  0{
        player!.play()
        print("<PLAYING")
    }else{
        player!.pause()
    }
}
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController plays:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe917802b80'
```

How can i recognize a 'click' or 'press' on the remote and make the Function `plays` do its work?

Comment: use a #selector in your target's action.

Comment: Add an underscore before the first parameter of your method. `func plays(_ sender: UIButton!)`

Comment: And the proper selector `#selector(plays(_:))`

Comment: Wauw... why couldn't i see that. Could you post as answer? ;)

Comment: Done. Just a note `player?.play()` Is safer and preferred over `player!.play()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 you need to an underscore before the first parameter of your method.

```
func plays(_ sender: UIButton!) {
```

And the proper selector syntax:

```
#selector(plays(_:))
```